# How to get the next id from mysql?

Tags: php, sql, database

I'm trying to get the ID from the next row in MySQL database.  How exactly would I do that?  The code I'm currently working with the following code.  I'm semi-new to PHP and SQL and also 15, so please be understanding if this isn't exactly right.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$GetNext = "SELECT * FROM sheep WHERE id = '> $row[id]' AND owner = $_SESSION[user_id] AND barn = $row[barn] AND pasture = $row[pasture]";
$get = mysqli_query($conn, $GetNextLeft);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get);
```

Comment: Do you mean the ID that will be assigned to the next row inserted?  Or the ID of another row in some sorting order?

Comment: @Wyzard The ID that is already assigned to the row

Comment: Warning: concatenating strings like this makes you vulnerable to SQL Injection.  You absolutely should be using Parameterized Queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `'LIMIT'` we can get 1 data.
We sort by `'ORDER BY id ASC'` we sort by small to large size.

```
$GetNext = "SELECT * FROM sheep WHERE id > $row[id] AND owner = $_SESSION[user_id] AND barn = $row[barn] AND pasture = $row[pasture] ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly what I needed!

Comment: Hey, you should at least address the SQL Injection problem, while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `order by` and `limit` such as:

```
select s.*
from sheep s
where id > ? and . . .
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

The `?` is a reminder that you should be using parameters in your queries, rather than munging query strings with input values.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the first id greater than row['id']? You should ORDER BY the id, than use limit to get only the first row.

Comment: So this works at first, but it only works once.  I need it to work every time.  I use the id to go to the next page, and once on the next page, the link no longer works.